# Java latest update security pop up

Tags: java, security, applet, warnings, signed-applet

How should I remove the security pop up from developer side? I don't want the user to keep clicking "don't block". I have all my *.jar file signed. Any help?

[image]

and if I have click more information
[image]

Again, as I said, I have all of my *.jar file signed. Is there anything else I need to signed? for example the php code?? or dll file?

Note: All the jar file are signed through thawte. It's not self-signed

Comment: Did you click on "More information"?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal I did. Check the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest update, Java no longer supports self-signed certificates. See [Java 7 Update 21 Security Improvements.](http://blog.eisele.net/2013/04/java-7-update-21-security-improvements.html)

Answer (score 0):

Java no longer supports self-signed certificates.

Comment: I'm not doing self-signed certificates. all my *.jar files are signed through thawte